# How do I import a csv file

Tags: python, csv, file-import

I'm trying to import a  file :

```
import pandas as pd
import os

Fig = pd.read_csv("Dataset.csv")
```

But it prompts an error that says :

> "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 14: invalid start byte"

Answer (score 2):

Your encoding is wrong. Use the `encoding` parameter to set it. For example,

```
pd.read_csv("Dataset.csv", encoding="utf8")
```